Minimal approach to deducing lots of template parameters
I frequently encounter a kind of problem illustrated in the following minimal hypothetical example.
I have a library function like this:
/**
 * `shoes` can take values {0, 1, 2}
 * `isNew` can take values {false, true}
 * `color` can take values {'r', 'g', 'b'}
 */
template <int shoes, bool isNew, char color>
int coreFun (int p1, int p2, int p3) {
  return shoes + isNew + int(color) + p1 + p2 + p3; // shoes price.
}

Now, I need to write a function for clients to use:
/**
 * Here, `shoes`, `isNew` and `color` will all be strings or string views
 * given by clients.
 * 
 * `p1`, `p2`, `p3` are variables to coreFun().
 */
int clientAPI (
    auto && shoes, auto && isNew, auto && color,
    int p1, int p2, int p3
) 
{
  int rst = 0; // result.
  if (shoes == "snicker") {
    if (isNew == "yes") {
      if (color == "red") rst = coreFun <0, true, 'r'> (p1, p2, p3);
      else if (color == "green") rst = coreFun <0, true, 'g'> (p1, p2, p3);
      else rst = coreFun <0, true, 'b'> (p1, p2, p3);
    }
    else { // isNew == "no"
      if (color == "red") rst = coreFun <0, false, 'r'> (p1, p2, p3);
      else if (color == "green") rst = coreFun <0, false, 'g'> (p1, p2, p3);
      else rst = coreFun <0, false, 'b'> (p1, p2, p3);
    }
  }
  else if (shoes == "leather") {
    if (isNew == "yes") {
      if (color == "red") rst = coreFun  <1, true, 'r'> (p1, p2, p3);
      else if (color == "green") rst = coreFun <1, true, 'g'> (p1, p2, p3);
      else rst = coreFun  <1, true, 'b'> (p1, p2, p3);
    }
    else { // isNew == "no"
      if (color == "red") rst = coreFun  <1, false, 'r'> (p1, p2, p3);
      else if (color == "green") rst = coreFun <1, false, 'g'> (p1, p2, p3);
      else rst = coreFun <1, true, 'b'> (p1, p2, p3);
    } 
  }
  else { // shoes == "other"
    if (isNew == "yes") {
      if (color == "red") rst = coreFun <2, true, 'r'> (p1, p2, p3);
      else if (color == "green") rst = coreFun <2, true, 'g'> (p1, p2, p3);
      else rst = coreFun <2, true, 'b'> (p1, p2, p3);
    }
    else { // isNew == "no"
      if (color == "red") rst = coreFun <2, false, 'r'> (p1, p2, p3);
      else if (color == "green") rst = coreFun <2, false, 'g'> (p1, p2, p3);
      else rst = coreFun <2, true, 'b'> (p1, p2, p3);
    }
  }
  return rst;
}

The signature of clientAPI() shall not be changed.
My implementation of clientAPI() works but is ridiculously long. Luckily in this example I only have 18 combinations. In real life I had encountered as many as 50 such template parameters. Pain.
I intend to simplify the implementation like the following:
int clientAPI (
    auto && shoes, auto && isNew, auto && color,
    int p1, int p2, int p3
) 
{
  using namespace std;
  auto clientInputs = tuple(move(shoes), move(isNew), move(color));
  constexpr auto mapping = tuple(
    tuple(pair("sniker", 0), pair("leather", 1), pair("other", 2)),
    tuple(pair("no", false), pair("yes", true)),
    tuple(pair("red", 'r'), pair("green", 'g'), pair("blue", 'b'))
  );
  
  
  // ===========================================================================
  // How to (i) achieve compile time deduction of the 18 instances
  // using a some kind of constexpr loop over `clientInputs` and `mapping`,
  // and then (ii) execute the correct instance of coreFun() 
  // corresponding to `clientInputs`?
  //
  // If the above is impossible, can we achieve the goal using
  // std::function and some kind of compile time lookup table ?
  // ===========================================================================
}

My question is listed in the comments above. Moreover, could there be some magic function / class that can take coreFun, clientInputs and mapping as parameters and produce the price of the shoes?
Many thanks!!

I would say this is a totally unecessary use of templates. The if else if (and the use of tuple/pair) are a clear sign something is wrong with this design. (It is overcomplicated). If I would encounter code like this during a code review I'd ask for simplification (showing off template coding skills for the sake of having them is not  goal). If you want to simplify,  get rid of the templates and see what you can do with a few constexpr functions

"be strings or string views" I would use std::string_view instead of auto&& as parameter in that case (so your function is not buggy if user passes C-strings)

You have a value conversion problem. All your string inputs need to be translate into enumeration values. There are 2 methods either switch+case for short number of values or a value mapping through arrays or other data types. The general  optimal solution is perfect hash functions, but it's too complicated.

You can use std::variant and std::integral_constant to do the conversion only once by type:
std::variant<std::false_type, std::true_type>
to_variant(bool b)
{
    switch (b) {
        case false: return std::false_type{};
        case true: return std::true_type{};
    }
}

std::variant<
    std::integral_constant<char, 'r'>,
    std::integral_constant<char, 'g'>,
    std::integral_constant<char, 'b'>
>
to_variant_color(std::string_view color)
{
    if (color == "red") {
        return std::integral_constant<char, 'r'>{};
    } else if (color == "green") {
        return std::integral_constant<char, 'g'>{};
    } else if (color == "blue") {
        return std::integral_constant<char, 'b'>{};
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid color");
}

std::variant<
    std::integral_constant<int, 0>,
    std::integral_constant<int, 1>,
    std::integral_constant<int, 2>
>
to_variant_shoes(std::string_view shoes)
{
    if (shoes == "snicker") {
        return std::integral_constant<int, 0>{};
    } else if (shoes == "leather") {
        return std::integral_constant<int, 1>{};
    } else if (shoes == "other") {
        return std::integral_constant<int, 2>{};
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid shoes");
}

Then, let std::visit do the dispatch:
int clientAPI (
    auto && shoes_str, auto && isNew_str, auto && color_str,
    int p1, int p2, int p3
)
{
    return std::visit(
        [&](auto shoes, auto isNew, auto color){
            return fun<shoes(), isNew(), color()>(p1, p2, p3)
        },
        to_variant_shoes(shoes_str),
        to_variant(isNew_str == std::string_view("true")),
        to_variant_color(color_str)
    );
}

Demo

Thank you for the answer. It is really helpful. However, could a function / class be designed to just take in clientInputs, mapping and coreFun, and produce the result?

coreFun is an overload set, you cannot pass it. You have to use another method, as making a class with operator().
